# setup cron tab to specific time of during weekdays

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to setup a cron job on a Ubuntu server. We want the cron job to run the script at certain times of the day and on some specific days of the week. For example, we want to setup a cron job that runs the script with the following sequence:

> Execute the script every 2 minutes from 9 am to 2 pm during the weekdays.

This is what I have been able to do so far:

> */2 09-14 * * * /path_to_script

What should I do for the weekdays?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Same as you did for hours:

```
*/2 09-18 * * 1-5 /path_to_script
```

`0` and `7` stand for Sunday
`6` stands for Saturday
so, `1-5` means from Monday to Friday

Answer (score 23):

You state 2pm in your requirement, hour range should end at 14 instead of 18 (which is 6pm).

```
*/2 9-14 * * 1-5 /path_to_script
```

man crontab

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5

Comment: heh +1 for pointing that out, but the time in the example was in general context :)

Answer (score 14):

In fact the last hour you want the script to run is 13:00 to 13:59, so you want:

```
*/2 9-13 * * 1-5 /path_to_script
```

meaning the first runtime will be 9:00, then 9:02, and so on until 13:58 which will be the last run as 14:00 is not included.