# I want the cron job to run the script weekly basis

Tags: cron, expression, jobs, job-scheduling

I am trying to setup a cron job on a Ubuntu server. I want the cron job to run the script on weekly basis. Problem is - It should be a working day, If im mentioning it with time interval, it fails during weekoffs - Need an Schedular Exp which has to work weekly only on working days at office hours.(9am to 9pm)max.

Want to Execute the script every week @6 pm during the weekdays. It Can be Mon to Fri.

Comment: Well, what prevents you from doing it? Please read [ask] and then show what you've tried and where exactly you failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setup cron tab to specific time of during weekdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436953/setup-cron-tab-to-specific-time-of-during-weekdays)

Comment: The tag `java` has nothing to do with your question, remove it.

Comment: @improbable probably not. cron exp is a common exp for a spring boot java apps

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov Only if you are using Scheduled of the Spring Framework. But, in fact, there is nothing about Java and/or Spring Framework in the actual question and there is no java code/snippets at all which makes me think the question has nothing to do with Java/Spring at all. And even if it would be a a case, spring tag must in place, not java.

Comment: sorry , ill keep tat in mind for next time.. tq @thomas

Comment: “At every 2nd minute past every hour from 9 through 18 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.” @PriyankaW - This is what the expression for the Cron. I need something like - which has to be executed weekly at Sometime only on WeekDays.

Answer (score 0):

Step1

```
sudo apt-get install cron

systemctl status cron
```

Step2
Configure the cron job:

```
crontab -e
```

Select an editor of your choice

```
0 0 * * 0 /path/to/command
```

**Syntax**: minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week command.

Day-of-week goes from 0-6 where 0 is Sunday.

Save it.